# Passing data between child components in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My goal is to use an onClick function in one of my components, and pass that data to another component (end goal is that in the other component called Playlist, it updates an array with the id of the clicked item).

I am just not sure how to pass the information between child components

My main component (app.jsx) looks like this

```
  const mainCards = Data.map(card => {
    return(
      <MainCard 
          key={card.id}
          id={card.id}
          image={card.url}
          title={card.title}
          playbutton={card.playbutton}
          addbutton={card.addbutton}
      />
    )
  })
  const sideCards = SideData.map(card => {
    return(
      <SideCard 
        image={card.sideurl}
        key={card.id}
        title={card.sidetitle}
        playbutton={card.playbutton}
        addbutton={card.addbutton}
      />
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <Playlist />
      <CardContainer />
      <div className="maincards">
          {mainCards}
      </div> 
      <div className="sidecards">
        {sideCards}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The component where I am using onClick (MainCard.jsx)

```
    const handleAdd = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
    }
    return(
        <div className="mainCardObject">
            <div className="cardObj">
                <img src={props.image} className ="mainCardImage"/>
                <img src={props.playbutton} className="playbutton"/>
                <img src={props.addbutton} onClick={() => handleAdd(props.id)} className="addbutton" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainCard
```

and the component I wish to pass information to (nothing inside, as I dont know where to start)

````
    return(
        <div className="playlistContainer">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )   
}
export default Playlist```
````

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you manage 'ids array' state globally creating a context, using the hook useContext(). Here a link with a simple explanation. I hope it helps!
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecontext.asp

Comment: Use handleAdd to update the context and mainCards should use the context data  to render cards.

Comment: hi @ЕмилЦоков I am fairly new to programming in react. What would that look like?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459756/how-do-i-update-an-array-using-the-usecontext-hook